# How to write $y_i=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\beta_k x_{ik}+\sqrt{u_i}\epsilon_i $ in matrix notation?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Normally, we can write the square of the error $\epsilon$ in the equation $y_i=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\beta_k x_{ik}+\epsilon_i$ in matrix notation as

$$(y-X\beta)^T (y-X\beta)$$

but how do we write the square of the same error in matrix notation from the equation $y_i=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\beta_k x_{ik}+\sqrt{u_i}\epsilon_i$, where $u$ is also a vector of the same length as $\epsilon$ and $y$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that your equation can be written as
$$
y = X\beta + D_u^{1/2} \epsilon,
$$
where $D_u$ is a diagonal matrix with the entries of $u$ on the diagonal.
Using this (as long as none of the $u_i$ are $0$), we can write
$$
\epsilon
= D_u^{-1/2}(y - X\beta)
$$
so that
$$
\lVert \epsilon \rVert^2
= \epsilon^{\mathrm{T}} \epsilon
= (y - X\beta)^{\mathrm{T}} D_u^{-1} (y - X\beta).
$$